# selecting the search result in watir

Tags: selenium-webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver, watir-classic

Currently i need to search a text and select the expected result from the search list.Search result displays with li tag and the text resides under span tag. Searching text will be like this Phone,Phone-audio,Phone-video .My source code is displaying like below..Please help me to select either Phone-audio or Phone-video.

```
<ul>
<li class="Searchitem"></li>
<span value="AL">Phone</span>
<li class="Searchitem"></li>
<span value="AL">Phone</span>-audio
<li class="Searchitem"></li>
<span value="AL">Phone</span>-video
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

That html doesn't make any sense, and definitely isn't per standard. Neither the span nor the -audio or -video are inside the li tags. I'm not even sure what element you need to click.

If it was html was compliant it would be as easy as:

`browser.span(text: 'Phone-video').when_present.click`

or maybe this would work, depending on the rest of the site's html, but it would be very flaky if anything changed:

`browser.ul.span(index: 1).when_present.click`